# C# Windows Form закруглёгнная кнопка

Tags: c#, button, background, round

Кнопка хорошо закругляется и всё работает, но только при наведение и отведение курсора появляться на миг белый фон и кнопка как бы мигает, пытался менять исправлять ничего не помогает. Прошу помощи!

```
public class RoundButton : Control
{
    public Color BackColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonBorderColor { get; set; }
    public int ButtonRoundRadius { get; set; }

    public Color ButtonHighlightColor { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonHighlightColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonHighlightForeColor { get; set; }

    public Color ButtonPressedColor { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonPressedColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonPressedForeColor { get; set; }

    private bool IsHighlighted;
    private bool IsPressed;

    public RoundButton()
    {
        Size = new Size(100, 40);
        ButtonRoundRadius = 30;
        BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
        BackColor2 = Color.Silver;
        ButtonBorderColor = Color.Black;
        ButtonHighlightColor = Color.Orange;
        ButtonHighlightColor2 = Color.OrangeRed;
        ButtonHighlightForeColor = Color.Black;

        ButtonPressedColor = Color.Red;
        ButtonPressedColor2 = Color.Maroon;
        ButtonPressedForeColor = Color.White;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
            createParams.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return createParams;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        var foreColor = IsPressed ? ButtonPressedForeColor : IsHighlighted ? ButtonHighlightForeColor : ForeColor;
        var backColor = IsPressed ? ButtonPressedColor : IsHighlighted ? ButtonHighlightColor : BackColor;
        var backColor2 = IsPressed ? ButtonPressedColor2 : IsHighlighted ? ButtonHighlightColor2 : BackColor2;


        using (var pen = new Pen(ButtonBorderColor, 1))
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, Path);

        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, backColor, backColor2, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, Path);

        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(foreColor))
        {
            var sf = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
            var rect = ClientRectangle;
            rect.Inflate(-4, -4);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, rect, sf);
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        IsHighlighted = true;
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        IsHighlighted = false;
        IsPressed = false;
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
        IsPressed = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
        IsPressed = false;
    }

    protected GraphicsPath Path
    {
        get
        {
            var rect = ClientRectangle;
            rect.Inflate(-1, -1);
            return GetRoundedRectangle(rect, ButtonRoundRadius);
        }
    }

    public static GraphicsPath GetRoundedRectangle(Rectangle rect, int d)
    {
        var gp = new GraphicsPath();

        gp.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, d, d, 180, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - d, rect.Y, d, d, 270, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - d, rect.Y + rect.Height - d, d, d, 0, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height - d, d, d, 90, 90);
        gp.CloseFigure();

        return gp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте [`Control.DoubleBuffered`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @aepot а куда мне его вписать ? (пишет что не существует в типе)

Comment: Возможно [сюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls)

Comment: @aepot нет не помогает, а ещё задний фон становиться чёрный а не прозрачный

Comment: В Windows Forms нет настоящей прозрачности (совсем), есть только псевдо-прозрачность, когда контрол сам берет цвет подложки. При включении буферизации у контрола не получается взять правильный фон, я не знаю, почему. Это означает, чтобы вам получить "прозрачный" фон, надо задать ему явно такой же как цвет, как у подложки под кнопкой. А что значит "не помогает", можете объяснить?

Comment: @aepot всё работает то правильно, контрол не может взять цвет фона потому что фон это картинка

Comment: Значит вам надо брать кусок картинки и рисовать его под контролом.

Comment: @aepot тут даже не в этом проблема, он просто почему то мигает, появляться белый квадрат, как будто происходит многочисленная отрисовка. Сам фон прозрачный, кнопка закруглённая, но вот она мигает белым когда наводишь быстро.

Comment: А еще (простите), можно перейти на WPF, и делать там такие кнопочки пачками прямо в xaml (можно с различными анимациями) без единой строчки кода на C#. С мерцаниями там проблем значительно меньше, а (полу)прозрачность там - нативная штуковина, поддерживаемая всем интерфейсом.

Comment: @aepot я знаю что WPF в этом обходит WindowsForm

Comment: К сожалению, проблема с мерцанием и прозрачностью в Winforms - та самая, последняя капля, которая заставила меня изучить WPF, и покинуть Winforms около 5 лет назад. Так что я сам был убит этой проблемой и победить ее не смог, но наверняка способ есть.

Comment: Еще есть [такое](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=netframework-4.8), попробовать стоит.

Comment: @aepot Я тоже задумываюсь переходить на WPF именно только из за прозрачности и более лёгкой анимации

Comment: WF уже почти мертва по сути